# How to include a LIKE clause in Rails query on HABTM join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models - Candidate and Keyword and has_and_belongs_to_many association between them.

If i want to find all candidates where a keyword.name equals to sth - i just need to do a search in Candidate model like this-and it works fine.

```
def self.search(search)
        includes(:keywords).where("keywords.name" => "#{search}")
end
```

But what if i need to search for candidates where keyword.name contains a string (equivalent of "LIKE" clause)? I've tried multiple ideas but cannot find a good solution...

Comment: What solutions have you tried?

Comment: just for the heck of it, wanted to point out that you can write what you currently have in a cleaner, more Rails-y way without a SQL string like this: `includes(:keywords).where(keywords: {name: search})`

Comment: @sixty4bit `{name: search}` uses `=` for search, it would be also nice to know if it's possible to use `LIKE` in hash conditions so that wildcard search also works.

Comment: @Sharj yes that would be nice. I doubt it would be possible because of the key-value nature of hashes. I'm guessing that with wildcards the only option is using a SQL string as in the answer. The closest thing I can think of is using an array as the value like this: `.where(key: [arr])` which will generate an `IN` clause in SQL, but that's still nowhere near as good as `LIKE` if you need to search a large number of possibilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

`.where("keywords.name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")`

*EDIT*

Note: this requires using `.joins` instead of `.includes` before the `WHERE` query.

Comment: Thx - but what if i am not using Postgres? I use MySQL

Comment: I've amended the answer because I don't think this is actually restricted to Postgres

Comment: The `WHERE column LIKE pattern` syntax is used in most SQL dialects including MySQL. The case-insentive `ILIKE` on the other hand is Postgres specific. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: Thanks @max. That must be what I was thinking of before.

Comment: @sixty4bit9 - if I write `.where("keywords.name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")` i get: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'keywords.name' in 'where clause': SELECT `candidates`.* FROM `candidates` WHERE (keywords.name LIKE '%test%')

Comment: @MaciekR try using `.joins` before `.where` instead of `.includes` and let me know if that makes any difference

Comment: @sixty4bit9 It works - thanks a lot. But to get unique results we have to add .uniq at the end. So the final query looks like this: `joins(:keywords).where('keywords.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%").uniq`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a LIKE query using the parameter replacement syntax, with any SQL dialect supported by RAILS:

```
def self.search(search)
  includes(:keywords).where("keywords.name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

This will replace the '?' in the query string with the amended search value to produce this SQL condition with a search string of "sth":

```
WHERE keywords.name LIKE '%sth%'
```

The search value is bookended with "%" (SQL wildcard character) outside the query string.  Including the "%" inside the query string will cause them to appear outside the quoted representation of the search value:

```
WHERE keywords.name LIKE %'sth'%
```

which will simply not work.